# Rearrange Negatives & Positives integer in an array using only one loop & no extra array

Tags: arrays, loops, sorting, data-structures

Is it possible (using only a single loop) to shift all the negative & positive integers to either sides of array without using any extra space?

Ex:

```
Input = [2,-4,45,-3,78,6,5,-72,8]

Output = [-3,-72,-4,2,45,78,8,5,6]

(Output order may Vary)
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to start with one index at the start of the array, and another at the end. Move the start index forward until you encounter a positive number. Then move the end index backwards until you find a negative number. Swap the two values, and begin moving the start index forward again. Continue in this fashion until the indexes meet.

So, given your example array:

```
[2,-4,45,-3,78,6,5,-72,8]
 ^                     ^
start                 end
```

`start` is pointing at a positive number, so move the `end` index backwards until you encounter a negative number:

```
[2,-4,45,-3,78,6,5,-72,8]
 ^                  ^
start              end
```

Swap the values

```
[-72,-4,45,-3,78,6,5,2,8]
  ^                  ^
 start              end
```

And then move the `start` index forward again until you find another positive number:

```
[-72,-4,45,-3,78,6,5,2,8]
        ^            ^
      start         end
```

Move `end` backwards to the next negative number:

```
[-72,-4,45,-3,78,6,5,2,8]
        ^   ^
      start end
```

swap

```
[-72,-4,-3,45,78,6,5,2,8]
        ^   ^
      start end
```

Move `start` forward and you encounter `end`, so you're done.

You can do that with a single loop. Coding it up is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using quick sort partition step. In quick sort, we partition the input array based on a pivot. The elements lesser than pivot will on the left side of the pivot and the elements greater than pivot will be on the right side of the pivot. In our case we can consider 0 as the pivot and apply the same partition step which is used in quicksort. After the partition step, the elements on the left side of the array will be less than 0 and the elements on the right will be greater than 0.

```
class Main {

  public void swap(int[] array,int x,int y){
    int temp = array[x];
    array[x] = array[y];
    array[y] = temp;
  }

  public void partition(int[] array){
    int posDelim = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++){
      if(array[i] < 0){
        swap(array,i,posDelim);
        posDelim++;
      }
    }
  }

  public void printArray(int[] array){
    for(int i : array)
      System.out.print(i + " ");
    System.out.println();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {2,-4,45,-3,78,6,5,-72,8};
    Main obj = new Main();
    obj.printArray(array);
    obj.partition(array);
    obj.printArray(array);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange positive and negative numbers

A simple solution is to use another array. We copy all elements of original array to new array. We then traverse the new array and copy all negative and positive elements back in original array one by one.The problem with this approach is that it uses auxiliary array and we’re not allowed to use any data structure to solve this problem.One approach that does not use any data structure is to use use partition process of QuickSort. The idea is to consider 0 as pivot and divide the array around it. The problem with this approach is that it changes relative order of elements

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(int arr[], int n)
{
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
printf("\n"); }
void RearrangePosNeg(int arr[], int n)

{
int key, j;
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    key = arr[i];
 if (key > 0)
        continue;

    j = i - 1;
    while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > 0)
    {
        arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        j = j - 1;
    }
    arr[j + 1] = key;
}
```

}

```
 int main()
```

{

```
 int arr[] = { -12, 11, -13, -5, 6, -7, 5, -3, -6 };

int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
 RearrangePosNeg(arr, n);

printArray(arr, n);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: "A simple solution is to use another array" ; this is not a solution, as the OP wanted a solution without using any extra space ; another array is a lot of extra space btw

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent Python Code:

```
def swap(array1,x,y):
    temp = array1[x]
    array1[x]=array1[y]
    array1[y]=temp
    return array1

array1 = [-2,-4,9,45,-3,78,6,5,-72,8]
index = 0
for i in range(len(array1)-1):
    if array1[i] < 0:
        swap(array1,i,index)
        index += 1
print(array1)
```

Thanks @Mainak & @Nisar

Answer (score 0):

```py
def rearrange(self, list):
    #Shift all negative at the start of the array
    i = -1
    for j in range(len(list)):
        if list[j] < 0:
            i += 1
            list[i], list[j] = list[j], list[i]
    k = i+1
    l=1
    while list[k-1] < 0:
        if l%2 !=0:
            temp = list[k]
            list[l+1:k+1] =list[l:k]
            list[l] = temp
            k += 1
            l += 2
        else:
            l += 1
return list
```

The idea is to move all negatives at the beginning of the array and then fixing the pointer to first positive in the array. Iterate over all the negatives to fix next positive integer on and after pointer before or after the negative values Python code for O(n) and O(1) memory